# Bridge (br0) not forwarding packets (RPi)

Tags: networking, bridge, forwarding

I'm currently in the middle of an LTE network project. I have two wwan interfaces (wwan0.1 and wwan0.2) and two Ethernet interfaces (eth0 and eth1). These interfaces are configured as shown below:

```
                       +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
                       | Raspberry Pi                                                                        |
                       |    +------------------+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+                            |
 +----------------+    |    |  +------------+  |    |     |    |     |    |     |    +-------------------+   |
 |  PC 1          |    |    |  |            |  |    |     |    |     |    |     |    | WWAN0.1 (Private) |   | 
 |  DHCP          |----+----+--|    ETH0    |  |    |     |    |     |    |     |<-->| Static            |   | 
 |  192.18.1.123  |    |    |  |            |  |    |  E  |    |  D  |    |  I  |    | 10.16.ppp.ppp     |   |
 +----------------+    |    |  +------------+  |    |  B  |    |  N  |    |  P  |    +-------------------+   |
                       |    |                  |    |  T  |    |  S  |    |     |                            |
                       |    |       BR0        |<-->|  A  |<-->|  M  |<-->|  R  |                            |
                       |    |                  |    |  B  |    |  A  |    |  O  |                            |
 +----------------+    |    |  +------------+  |    |  L  |    |  S  |    |  U  |    +-------------------+   |
 |  PC 2          |    |    |  |            |  |    |  E  |    |  Q  |    |  T  |    | WWAN0.1 (Public)  |   |
 |  DHCP          |----+----+--|    ETH1    |  |    |  S  |    |     |    |  E  |<-->| DHCP              |   |
 |  192.18.1.169  |    |    |  |            |  |    |     |    |     |    |     |    | 10.xxx.xxx.xxx    |   |
 +----------------+    |    |  +------------+  |    |     |    |     |    |     |    +-------------------+   |
                       |    +------------------+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+                            |
                       |                                                                                     |
                       +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The following works:

- From the RPi I can ping a server on the private network wwan0.1
- From the RPi I can ping a server on the public network wwan0.2
- PC1 and PC2 are allocated an IP address from DNSMasq (via br0)
- From PC1 I can ping PC2
- From PC2 I can ping PC1
- From PC1 and PC2, I can ping the RPi (192.168.1.1)
- From PC1 and PC2, I can connect to the RPi via SSH (192.168.1.1)

However the following does not work:

- I cannot ping anything on the private or public networks from PC1
- I cannot ping anything on the private or public networks from PC2

Here is my current setup

**brctl**

```
brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.0050b69c9bf5       no              eth0
                                                        eth1
```

**ebtables**

```
Bridge table: filter

Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 4, policy: DROP
-p IPv4 -j ACCEPT
-p ARP -j ACCEPT
-j ACCEPT
--log-level info --log-prefix "EBFW" --log-ip -j CONTINUE

Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 4, policy: DROP
-p IPv4 -j ACCEPT
-p ARP -j ACCEPT
-j ACCEPT
--log-level info --log-prefix "EBFW" --log-ip -j CONTINUE

Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 4, policy: DROP
-p IPv4 -j ACCEPT
-p ARP -j ACCEPT
-j ACCEPT
--log-level info --log-prefix "EBFW" --log-ip --log-arp -j DROP
```

**sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.br0.bc_forwarding=1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

**ip route**

```
default dev wwan0.2 scope link
10.16.ppp.ppp/30 dev wwan0.1 proto kernel scope link src 10.16.ppp.ppp
10.xxx.xxx.xxx/29 dev wwan0.2 proto kernel scope link src 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
10.10.124.0/24 dev wwan0.1 scope link
10.100.0.0/22 dev wwan0.1 scope link
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
```

Anyone know what the missing piece is?

Cheers,

Lee

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss the NAT part, as would require any router routing between a LAN using private IP addresses on one side and public IP addresses on the other side.

Something as simple as:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o wwan+ -j MASQUERADE
```

If you have total control of the wwan and its remote side too, one could imagine the remote devices on the private part (wwan0.1) could receive direct routes to 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.16.ppp.ppp instead of using NAT on the RPi, but the possibility to do that would depend on how the communication is implemented.